# Changing choropleth symbology with drop down @ plotly

Tags: python, pandas, button, plotly, choropleth

Hi I am quite new to plotly and trying to create a choropleth covid map with different symbology with a button selector. problem I have is I can’t achieve different symbology.

Thanks in advance!

Here’s what I have so far:

````
df= pd.read_csv (covid.csv)
data=dict(type=‘choropleth’,
locations = df[‘Name’],
locationmode = ‘country names’,
z = df[‘Total’] # I believe here is my problem if I do z=[‘total’, ‘1M_pop’] I lost data
marker_line_color = ‘black’,
marker_line_width = 0.5,
)

layout=dict(title_text = ‘Cases today by country’,
title_x = 0.5,
geo=dict(
showframe = True,
showcoastlines = True,
projection_type = ‘mercator’
)
)
map=go.Figure( data=[data], layout =layout)

#buttons test
fig[“layout”]
fig[“layout”].pop(“updatemenus”)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds=“locations”, visible=True)

button1 = dict(method = “restyle”,
args = [{‘z’: [ df[“Total”] ] }, [“colorscale”, “Greens”]],
label = “Total Cases”)
button2 = dict(method = “restyle”,
args = [{‘z’: [ df[“1M_pop”] ]},[“colorscale”, “reds”]],
label = “Cases per 1M”)

fig.update_layout(width=1000,
coloraxis_colorbar_thickness=23,
updatemenus=[dict(y=1.1,
x=0.275,
xanchor=‘right’,
yanchor=‘bottom’,
active=0,
buttons=[button1, button2])
])
plot(fig, filename=‘covid.html’)``` 





[plotly][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV3gh.png
````

Comment: Hi Omri, Welcome to Stack Overflow! The link there isn't formatted properly. Please check the preview of your post and fix the link. Please be careful next time and always remember double check and review your question before posting. Goodluck :D

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

- have plugged in OWID data to make it re-producable. Additionally you quotes and double-quotes were unusable so had to change to standard quote
- I could get changes in **z** to work in **updatemenus**. Getting **colorscale** to work was not working
- switched techniques,  generate two similar traces then use **updatemenus** to control visibility

```
import requests, io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# df= pd.read_csv (covid.csv)
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.csv"
        ).text
    )
)
df = df.rename(
    columns={
        "location": "Name",
        "total_cases": "Total",
        "total_cases_per_million": "1M_pop",
    }
)

data = dict(
    type="choropleth",
    locations=df["Name"],
    colorscale="reds",
    locationmode="country names",
    z=df[
        "Total"
    ],  # I believe here is my problem if I do z=['total', '1M_pop'] I lost data
    marker_line_color="black",
    marker_line_width=0.5,
)

layout = dict(
    title_text="Cases today by country",
    title_x=0.5,
    geo=dict(showframe=True, showcoastlines=True, projection_type="mercator"),
)
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        data,
        {**data, **{"z": df["1M_pop"], "colorscale": "blues", "visible": False}},
    ],
    layout=layout,
)

# buttons test
fig["layout"]
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)

button1 = dict(
    method="update",
    args=[{"visible": [True, False]}],
    label="Total Cases",
)
button2 = dict(
    method="update",
    args=[{"visible": [False, True]}],
    label="Cases per 1M",
)

fig.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    coloraxis_colorbar_thickness=23,
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            y=1.1,
            x=0.275,
            xanchor="right",
            yanchor="bottom",
            active=0,
            buttons=[button1, button2],
        )
    ],
)

fig
```